# How do I update a user's mailbox timezone via Graph API in C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

It may be tempting to mark this code as a duplicate of an earlier post, but this relates to a newer version of Graph, and I believe this functionality is supposed to be supported now, whereas with other posts I've seen on SO they relate to an earlier version that didn't support this functionality.

According to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update-mailboxsettings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) it is presently possible to update user Mailbox Settings via the Graph API. The example at the link shows how to update Automatic Replies via C#, and specifies a number of other fields that can be updated, including the Timezone.

I am using [Microsoft.Graph 3.5.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph/3.5.0) for this code.

However, when I try to run this code:

```
    public async Task ResetMailboxTimezone(string id)
    {
        // id is a string version of a valid Guid with hyphens
        const string defaultTimezone = "AUS Eastern Standard Time";
        var newUser = new User();
        var mbs = new MailboxSettings
        {
            AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                {"@odata.context", $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('{id}')/mailboxSettings"}
            },
            TimeZone = defaultTimezone
        };
        newUser.MailboxSettings = mbs;

        await _graphServiceClient.Users[azureGuid].Request().UpdateAsync(userChanges);
    }
```

I get an exception:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function: UpdateMailboxTimezone
 ---> Status Code: MethodNotAllowed
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: ErrorInvalidRequest
Message: The OData request is not supported.
Inner error:
        AdditionalData:
        request-id: 246cb7f8-9f33-462c-82f1-3e41fd349053
        date: 2020-05-18T10:12:51
ClientRequestId: 246cb7f8-9f33-462c-82f1-3e41fd349053
at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendRequestAsync(Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendAsync[T](Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
```

Additional clarification: This is running under App permissions, and the App has been granted permissions for this activity.I can READ the timezone from any account successfully, but I can't update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```cs
  public async Task ResetMailboxTimezone(string id) {
   const string defaultTimezone = "AUS Eastern Standard Time";
   var mbs = new MailboxSettings {
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary < string, object > {
      {
       "@odata.context",
       $ "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('{id}')/mailboxSettings"
      }
     },
     TimeZone = defaultTimezone,
   };

   // Build your request url
   string requestUrl = $ "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/mailboxsettings";
   var hrm = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Patch, requestUrl) {
    Content = new StringContent(_graphServiceClient.HttpProvider.Serializer.SerializeObject(mbs), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
   };

   // Authenticate (add access token) our HttpRequestMessage
   await _graphServiceClient.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(hrm);

   // Send the request
   await _graphServiceClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(hrm);
  }
```

Comment: Apart from the authentication being redundant in my case, this works fine once I removed that line. Feels strange feeding an HTTP request in, but at least it is being done via the GraphServiceClient. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @dylanT HTTP requests are used internally, here we have to explicitly use them since there is no MailboxSettings collection request available.